# jQuery stopping after parseJSON

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.get('api/dosomething.php',data,function(responseText){
    alert(responseText);
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
    alert(response);
```

The first alert says: `Object (object)`

However, the next alert is never executed.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) file.php:1
4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

PHP:

```
 $result = array('id' => $db->lastInsertId());

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Probablt your server side json format is not exceptable. Try JSON.parse a well.

Comment: *"The first alert says: Object (object)..."* Then `responseText` is already an object. You cannot parse it, the response *was* already parsed and that's the result of the parsing. `jQuery.parseJSON` expects a **string** containing JSON.

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` as it automatically convert the object to string and displays the data in readable format. In your case do `console.log(responseText)` and observe the result. If required install 'Firebug' like plugin for your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script tells the browser that you are serving JSON (`Content-Type: application/json`). $.get automatically detects that and converts the fetched JSON data to a valid JavaScript object.

```
$.get('api/dosomething.php',data,function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types:

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery then rely on the built in getJSON functionality.

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function(data){
  // do your work here using data as a JSON object
});
```

data is already a Javascript object and you can start using it right away.

Comment: *"data is already in JSON format and you can start using it right away"* No no no! `data` is already a JavaScript object. An object is not in "JSON format" (whatever that means). An object is just an object. Also: [There is no such thing is a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either `data` is a string containing JSON or jQuery already parsed the string and it is an object. You seem to mix both things in your description and that makes it quite confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right in that the choice of words was bad. Fortunately the concepts are not mixed in my head, but I edited the answer nonetheless and thanks for pointing it out.